# android preference change diplayed preferences in same PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have two preference xml files. The first one (pref2.xml) contains 2 preferences:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <CheckBoxPreference 
        android:key="key"
        android:title="title" 
        android:defaultValue="false"
    />
   <CheckBoxPreference 
        android:key="key2"
        android:title="title" 
        android:defaultValue="false"
    />
 </PreferenceScreen>
```

and the other one (pref1.xml) contains 1 preference:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <CheckBoxPreference 
        android:key="key"
        android:title="title" 
        android:defaultValue="false"
    />

 </PreferenceScreen>
```

in my preference activity I am trying to change them:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   

            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref1);
            this.getPreferenceScreen().removeAll();
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref2);
            final ListAdapter adapter = getPreferenceScreen().getRootAdapter();
            Log.d("LOG", "size of sharedPreferences"+adapter.getCount()+"(should be 2)");
```

actually here i get the right output and everything is displayed correctly. But I want to change the displayed preferences concerning one preference. Therefore I implemented the OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener in the preference activity:

```
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
    super.onSharedPreferenceChanged(sharedPreferences, key);

    //switch the widget type
    if (key.equals("key")){
        this.getPreferenceScreen().removeAll();
                    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref1);
                    final ListAdapter adapter = getPreferenceScreen().getRootAdapter();
                    Log.d("LOG", "size of sharedPreferences "+adapter.getCount()+" (should be 1)");
    }
 }
```

Well, the pref1 preferences are displayed correctly, but the output of

> "size of sharedPreferences 2"

indicated that in the background there are still the old preferences applied. If i iterate over the listAdapter i get also the old preferences.

### Any idea how I could solve this?

I found out that the listadapter is some how outdated. If I get the count of items via getPreferenceScreen().getPreferenceCount() I get the right amount. But how do I access these preferences ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure that problem lies with your having two preferences with a key of "key" even though they are on different screens. A preference is identified by its key and this needs to be unique to avoid conflicts. The listener only knows which preference is being changed from the key. I would change the keys to have unique values.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Well, wasn't right :S

...

Okey, I finally found the solution. After changing the PreferenceScreen I need to bind manually the listView again:

```
 getPreferenceScreen().bind((ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list));
```